# Numpy setup error : extra formal argument

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, fortran, setup.py

I have some Fortran files I would like to use in Python files. I have used the command C:\Python27\python.exe setup.py build_ext --inplace --fcompiler=g95. My setup.py file contains the following code:

```
import sys, os
extra_link_args = []
extra_link_args = ['-framework', 'accelerate']
from numpy.distutils.core import setup, Extension
opt_flags = ['-g', '-fbounds-check', '-I/usr/include/']
files1 = ['particle_solvers/fbsl_sim_fmod.f90',
          'particle_solvers/fbsl_parts_fmod.f90',
          'particle_solvers/fbsl_poisson_fmod.f90',
          'particle_solvers/fbsl_convol_fmod.f90',
          'particle_solvers/fbsl_lbfr_parts_fmod.f90',
          'particle_solvers/fbsl_ltp_parts_fmod.f90',
          'particle_solvers/fbsl_pusher_fmod.f90',
          ]
ext1 = Extension(name='_fbsl_f90',
                 sources=files1,
                 extra_compile_args=opt_flags,
                 extra_link_args=extra_link_args)
setup(name="_fbsl_f90",
      version='0.1',
      description="Hidden",
      author="Hidden",
      author_email='Hidden',
      url='',
      ext_modules=[ext1])
```

But I have got the following errors :

```
g95.exe:f90: build\src.win32-2.7\_fbsl_f90-f2pywrappers2.f90
In file build\src.win32-2.7\_fbsl_f90-f2pywrappers2.f90:211
     &ef2pywrap, smooth_heaviside, r)
                                   1
Error: Extra formal argument for 'f2pywrap_fbsl_sim_f90_smooth_heaviside' at (1)
In file build\src.win32-2.7\_fbsl_f90-f2pywrappers2.f90:13
     &nf2pywrap, t)
                 1
In file build\src.win32-2.7\_fbsl_f90-f2pywrappers2.f90:217
     &nf2pywrap, f_exact_is_known, t)
                 2
Error: Differing types REAL(8) and LOGICAL(4) in formal arguments at (1) and (2)
In file build\src.win32-2.7\_fbsl_f90-f2pywrappers2.f90:223
     &inal_is_knownf2pywrap, f_exact_final_is_known)
                             1
Error: Extra formal argument for 'f2pywrap_fbsl_sim_f90_f_exact_final_is_known'
at (1)
In file build\src.win32-2.7\_fbsl_f90-f2pywrappers2.f90:228
     &2pywrap, f_exact_initial, eta_0, eta_1)
                                       1
Error: Extra formal argument for 'f2pywrap_fbsl_sim_f90_f_exact_initial' at (1)
In file build\src.win32-2.7\_fbsl_f90-f2pywrappers2.f90:235
     &, t, eta_0, eta_1)
                  1
Error: Extra formal argument for 'f2pywrap_fbsl_sim_f90_f_exact' at (1)
In file build\src.win32-2.7\_fbsl_f90-f2pywrappers2.f90:243
     &rap, f_exact_final, eta_0, eta_1)
                                 1
Error: Extra formal argument for 'f2pywrap_fbsl_sim_f90_f_exact_final' at (1)
In file build\src.win32-2.7\_fbsl_f90-f2pywrappers2.f90:250
     &_field_is_givenf2pywrap, velocity_field_is_given)
                               1
Error: Extra formal argument for 'f2pywrap_fbsl_sim_f90_velocity_field_is_given'
 at (1)
In file build\src.win32-2.7\_fbsl_f90-f2pywrappers2.f90:255
     &ine_u0, x0, x1)
                  1
Error: Extra formal argument for 'f2pywrap_fbsl_sim_f90_affine_u0' at (1)
In file build\src.win32-2.7\_fbsl_f90-f2pywrappers2.f90:262
     &ine_u1, x0, x1)
                  1
Error: Extra formal argument for 'f2pywrap_fbsl_sim_f90_affine_u1' at (1)
In file build\src.win32-2.7\_fbsl_f90-f2pywrappers2.f90:269
     &p, quadratic_u0, t, x0, x1)
                              1
Error: Extra formal argument for 'f2pywrap_fbsl_sim_f90_quadratic_u0' at (1)
In file build\src.win32-2.7\_fbsl_f90-f2pywrappers2.f90:277
     &p, quadratic_u1, t, x0, x1)
                              1
Error: Extra formal argument for 'f2pywrap_fbsl_sim_f90_quadratic_u1' at (1)
In file build\src.win32-2.7\_fbsl_f90-f2pywrappers2.f90:285
     &w_0f2pywrap, bwd_affine_flow_0, t, x0, x1)
                                             1
Error: Extra formal argument for 'f2pywrap_fbsl_sim_f90_bwd_affine_flow_0' at (1
)
In file build\src.win32-2.7\_fbsl_f90-f2pywrappers2.f90:293
     &w_1f2pywrap, bwd_affine_flow_1, t, x0, x1)
                                             1
Error: Extra formal argument for 'f2pywrap_fbsl_sim_f90_bwd_affine_flow_1' at (1
)
In file build\src.win32-2.7\_fbsl_f90-f2pywrappers2.f90:301
     &ic_flow_0f2pywrap, bwd_quadratic_flow_0, t, x0, x1)
                                                      1
Error: Extra formal argument for 'f2pywrap_fbsl_sim_f90_bwd_quadratic_flow_0' at
 (1)
In file build\src.win32-2.7\_fbsl_f90-f2pywrappers2.f90:309
     &ic_flow_1f2pywrap, bwd_quadratic_flow_1, t, x0, x1)
                                                      1
Error: Extra formal argument for 'f2pywrap_fbsl_sim_f90_bwd_quadratic_flow_1' at
 (1)
In file build\src.win32-2.7\_fbsl_f90-f2pywrappers2.f90:317
     &0, x1)
         1
Error: Extra formal argument for 'f2pywrap_fbsl_sim_f90_bggk_a' at (1)
error: Command "C:\Users\QUENTIN\bin\g95.exe -fno-second-underscore -O -Ibuild\s
rc.win32-2.7 -IC:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Python27\in
clude -IC:\Python27\PC -c -c build\src.win32-2.7\_fbsl_f90-f2pywrappers2.f90 -o
build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\build\src.win32-2.7\_fbsl_f90-f2pywrappers2.o -fmod
=build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\ -Ibuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\" failed with exit
 status 1
```

I don't understand why I have those Extra formal argument errors. How can I fix them ? I am working on Windows 7 with Python 2.7 and g95 compiler.

EDIT : Okay, to simplify, here is a sample of my Fortran code :

```
module test_f90

implicit none

real *8 :: delta

contains

real*8 function test_f(r)
    real*8, intent(in) :: r
    test_f = 0.5*( 1 + erf(r/delta) )
end function

end module test_f90
```

When I use the command C:\Python27\python.exe setup.py build_ext --inplace --fcompiler=g95 with this setup.py file :

```
import sys

extra_link_args = []

from numpy.distutils.core import setup, Extension

opt_flags = ['-g', '-fbounds-check', '-I/usr/include/']


files1 = ['test_fmod.f90',
          ]


ext1 = Extension(name='_test_f90',
                 sources=files1,
                 extra_compile_args=opt_flags,
                 extra_link_args=extra_link_args)


setup(name="_test_f90",
      version='0.1',
      description="test module",
      author="Hidden",
      author_email='Hidden',
      url='',
      ext_modules=[ext1])
```

I have got this Fortran file generated by f2py :

```
!     -*- f90 -*-
!     This file is autogenerated with f2py (version:2)
!     It contains Fortran 90 wrappers to fortran functions.

      subroutine f2pywrap_test_f90_test_f (test_ff2pywrap, r)
      use test_f90, only : test_f
      real(kind=8) r
      real(kind=8) test_ff2pywrap
      test_ff2pywrap = test_f(r)
      end subroutine f2pywrap_test_f90_test_f

      subroutine f2pyinittest_f90(f2pysetupfunc)
      use test_f90, only : delta
      interface 
      subroutine f2pywrap_test_f90_test_f (test_ff2pywrap, test_f, r)
      real(kind=8) test_f
      real(kind=8) r
      real(kind=8) test_ff2pywrap
      end subroutine f2pywrap_test_f90_test_f
      end interface
      external f2pysetupfunc
      call f2pysetupfunc(delta,f2pywrap_test_f90_test_f)
      end subroutine f2pyinittest_f90
```

but I still have this error :

```
g95.exe:f90: build\src.win32-2.7\_test_f90-f2pywrappers2.f90
In file build\src.win32-2.7\_test_f90-f2pywrappers2.f90:15

      subroutine f2pywrap_test_f90_test_f (test_ff2pywrap, test_f, r)
                                                                   1
Error: Extra formal argument for 'f2pywrap_test_f90_test_f' at (1)
error: Command "C:\Users\QUENTIN\bin\g95.exe -fno-second-underscore -O -Ibuild\s
rc.win32-2.7 -IC:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Python27\in
clude -IC:\Python27\PC -c -c build\src.win32-2.7\_test_f90-f2pywrappers2.f90 -o
build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\build\src.win32-2.7\_test_f90-f2pywrappers2.o -fmod
=build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\ -Ibuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\" failed with exit
 status 1
```

Comment: Those errors seem to result from mis-calling Fortran subroutines.  Of course, that's just a guess because you haven't shown us the code.

Comment: Please show us the Fortran code that is resulting in these errors.

Comment: I have edited my post with a piece of my Fortran code

Comment: Have you tried removing the `implicit none` and the `real *8 :: delta` lines? It looks like f2py in interpreting delta as a function.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, it appears the f2py wrapper support is broken, as it declares 
a function twice with conflicting signatures: first 2 then 3 formal arguments. It's not clear this version will work for you as desired, though you might find it useful to work through the examples of the first few [f2py ToC](https://web.archive.org/web/20171114052658/https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/f2py/) entries.

Answer (score 0):

it shows numpy is not install properly. you can download the numpy from the following link

```
https://pypi.org/project/numpy/
```

or you can use wheel file to install numpy.

Go to the following line to download the suitable wheel. 
https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

on above link search numpy and install it

Answer (score -5):

https://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/?source=typ_redirect
Above mention, the link has the source file of numpy download it.

Then fire a command in terminal.

cd /home/Downloads/numpy-1.11.2

ls

sudo python setup.py install

Comment: What will this solve? Also, I don't think the OP has any `/home/Downloads` directory.

Comment: This will use to resolve the problem of to setup numpy.

Comment: cd /home/Downloads means you have to use your common sense and changed the dictionary to your downloaded file path or reach to your set up file.